# Do you need to call init_timer() again after a del_timer()

Tags: linux, timer, module, kernel

I have a `Linux` module which creates timers, some of which may add themselves again during their handler function.

In some other cases, the timer is removed (perhaps before it's gone off) using `del_timer_sync()`.

In that case, do I need to do the `init_timer()` call again on the struct before I next `add_timer(`) or is that just a waste of (precious) interrupt latency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, I believe I do need to init_timer() my struct after any del_timer() or del_timer_sync() if I ever intend to access the struct again - for example, when doing a timer_pending() or something during module cleanup.

I think in the case of writing a kernel module which potentially re-uses a timer, the best thing to do is:

```
static struct timer_list my_timer;

...

static void remove_my_timer(void)
{
  if (timer_pending(&my_timer))
  {
    del_timer_sync(&my_timer);
    init_timer(&my_timer);
  }
}

static void arm_my_timer(...)
{
  remove_my_timer();
  my_timer.expires  = ...;
  my_timer.data     = ...;
  my_timer.function = ...;
  add_timer(&my_timer);
}

...

int __init init_my_device(void)
{
  ...
  init_timer(&my_timer);
  ...
}

void __exit cleanup_my_device(void)
{
  ...
  remove_my_timer();
  ...
}
```

Hope that helps someone else in future.