# Linux kernel timer init_timer. What happens if called many times?

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am trying to hunt a bug that cause intermittent crash at PC around get_next_timer_interrupt() code and sometimes at run_timer_softirq()

I found a driver that potentially calls init_timer() often with the same static argument passed to it. (timer_list)

Will this cause issue?

What exactly does init_timer do and is there a function that does the reverse to destroy it?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19979276/do-you-need-to-call-init-timer-again-after-a-del-timer

Answer (score 2):

Calling `init_timer()` a lot should not cause any problem.  The code which is eventually invoked [is](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/timer.c#L621):

```
621 static void do_init_timer(struct timer_list *timer, unsigned int flags,
622                           const char *name, struct lock_class_key *key)
623 {
624         struct tvec_base *base = __raw_get_cpu_var(tvec_bases);
625 
626         timer->entry.next = NULL;
627         timer->base = (void *)((unsigned long)base | flags);
628         timer->slack = -1;
629 #ifdef CONFIG_TIMER_STATS
630         timer->start_site = NULL;
631         timer->start_pid = -1;
632         memset(timer->start_comm, 0, TASK_COMM_LEN);
633 #endif
634         lockdep_init_map(&timer->lockdep_map, name, key, 0);
635 }
```

That gets invoked by a few macros calling down to it.  Start [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=init_timer) to follow the flow.